# What would be the result of giving 777 ( r w x to all ) permissions to every file in a system?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Say, if I ran `sudo chmod -R 777 /` or something similar, will it have a negative effect on the OS in terms of performance,etc?

This is mostly theoretical, but I almost did it by mistake, so wanted to ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been addressed quite well in this Server Fault question: [Why is “chmod -R 777 /” destructive?](https://serverfault.com/questions/364677/why-is-chmod-r-777-destructive), so I will summarize:

Basically, by doing that you let everyone access every file on your system. In this situation, many programs will refuse to run since they check and expect permissions, and programs that rely on `setgid`/`setuid` also have lost those permissions.

The system **might** work after this command, but results will be unpredictable when you need to restart a service or to reboot.

As for performance, it will most likely not have any effect.

Answer (score 4):

From a security point of view, this can have disastrous results. This means that any user on the system (take into consideration the default ones too - some of which are created by the applications you install) has access to any file. This not only means that any user could execute anything on your system (ex: install a flood tool and launch a DoS attack on another host), but they would have access to any sensitive data too (your personal data and also password data, most probably in an encrypted way but still it represents a risk see [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/)).

Setting those permissions would be like permissions are useless. It's more than bad practice to do so. From my point of view, there should be a confirmation note stating the risks and if you still want to continue...